# How to use checkbox to select my data

Tags: sql, vb.net

i am using vb.net with microsoft sql
i want to retrieve data where the checkbox is selected how could i perform it?
this the code i currently have

```vb
Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk)
chk.HeaderText = "Select"
chk.Name = "lol"

sql.RunQuery("Select ID,JobPosition,requiredQualification,Salary, description,JobExpYear from vacancy where JobPosition IN (Select JobPosition from employer where EID = '" & ID & "')")

If sql.SQLDS.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    DataGridView1.DataSource = sql.SQLDS.Tables(0)
End If
```

i will have checkbox within my data grid, how do i call it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, question not clear enough for me. But see if this helps:

```
Dim condition As String = String.Empty
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    condition += DirectCast(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Selected.ToString + ", "
Next

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(condition) Then
    'Remove last splitter
    condition = condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 2)
End If
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you can vote to close the question as unclear, if you are not sure what OP meant. Alternatively, you can request clarification in the comments.

Comment: But what might be the reason of a downvote for this :/
Unfair :@

Comment: Perhaps another person understood the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your question: ***"i am using vb.net with microsoft sql i want to retrieve data where the checkbox is selected how could i perform it?"***

There are a few different ways that this can be accomplished. You can either one, create a function that returns if it's checked or not or create a method that does all of your logic for you, it depends on *how your going to use it*. According to your query your not getting any information from the `DataGridView`, you are saying you want to retrieve data if it's checked or not. Another question is what is the purpose of running the same query if you have multiple rows, are you going to be running different queries based on the `CheckBox` for that row if it's checked?

**Example 1** -Create a function to see what the value is

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns if given column is checked or not
''' </summary>
''' <param name="dGrid"></param>
''' <param name="dRow"></param>
''' <param name="intIndex"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function IsColumnChecked(ByVal dGrid As DataGridView, ByVal dRow As DataGridViewRow, ByVal intIndex As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim blnIsChecked As Boolean = False

    Try
        'What column is the checkboxcolumn and let's make sure its the correct type
        If TypeOf (dGrid.Columns(intIndex)) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Then
            If dGrid.RowCount <> 0 Then
                If CBool(DirectCast(dRow.Cells(intIndex), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value) Then
                    blnIsChecked = True
                End If
            Else
                Return blnIsChecked
            End If
        Else
            Return blnIsChecked
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return blnIsChecked
    End Try

    Return blnIsChecked
End Function
```

**Example 1 Useage** - Check to see if given row is checked or not-

```
 'Example ONLY on a button click...
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If IsColumnChecked(DataGridView1, DataGridView1.CurrentRow, 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("It's Checked!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Checked!")
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also put this in a method to do what you want with other logic, not sure how you are going to use it. This function is good to determine if you want to continue with other things or not and can be used in other areas of your program as well.

Good Luck!